# Clustering of matrices

Tags: terminology, reference-request, matrices, permutations

I have a matrix of n lines and T columns, containing only 0's or 1's.

I would like to make permutations of lines (and lines only) to make the largest submatrix of 1's possible (i.e. i want to find sqaures of 1's in my matrix).

I thought of it as matrix clustering, but google remains silent; Does this problem have a name in computer science ?

I am also interested in the similar problem where one can apply permutations on both lines and columns.

Thanks,

Edit : Found out about Biclustering (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Biclustering), which is exactly it. Thanks again !

Comment: What's a submatrix for you? Are the rows and columns contiguous or not? Also, how do you mention largeness?

Comment: Try searching for the phrase "complete bipartite subgraph". Yuval raises an interesting point as to what you mean by "largest". There are a few interesting results here if you just consider the square submatrix case (known as the balanced complete bipartite subgraph problem). Finding a balanced bipartite subgraph of a given size is known to be NP-complete. Finding the maximum balanced bipartite subgraph is NP-hard.

Comment: Thanks for the answers, and sorry if my question was unclear. I am not looking for solutions (for example, bipartite graphs -- which I am already using :) ), but for names this problem might have, to build a state of the art of this problem.

Comment: Perhaps you should answer your own question now.

Comment: Rather than answering "Edit: I found the answer, nevermind", you should answer your own question.  Also, rather than posting a comment with clarifications, you should edit the question to clarify the question.  We want questions to be self-contained (so there's no need to read the comment thread), and part of our mission is to build up a repository of high-quality questions and answers.